# Content type field to include both media entities and links

Tags: 8, nodes, media

I'm new to Drupal and I'm creating a new content type. I know there's two separate fields for media and links, but is there a field that include both? For example, the field is called "News Releases", a user can upload a document and/or include a link. Or would I need to create two separate fields and have one called "News Releases" and "News Releases 2" for media and links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is probably to use the [paragraphs](https://drupal.org/project/paragraphs) module and create a paragraph type of "News release" that contains the media field and the link field, then create an instance of that paragraph field on your content type.

Comment: That worked perfectly and learned something new, thanks!!